# Firebase cloud function doesn't send push notification with async

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

My goal is to send a push notification when a user sends a message. I am trying to do this by retrieving all of the push tokens from the firestore database, and sending a multicast message using these tokens each time a new message is added to the realtime database.

## Works

This first example works. There is no token retrieval, the tokens are hardcoded. I do receive the notifications.

```dart
exports.notifyUsers = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onCreate((liveSnapshot, context) => {
    const name = context.params.messageId;
    const message = liveSnapshot.val().toString();
    const tokens = [
         "e6erA_qM...",
         "ePU9p_CI...",
    ];
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: `New message from ${name}`,
            body: message,
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default'
        },
        tokens: tokens,
    }
    const res = admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload);   
    console.log(`response: ${res}`);
```

## Doesn't work

This doesn't work, I don't receive any notifications.

```dart
exports.notifyUsers = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onCreate(async (liveSnapshot, context) => {
    const name = context.params.messageId;
    const message = liveSnapshot.val().toString();
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').get();
    const tokens = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().token);
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: `New message from ${name}`,
            body: message,
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default'
        },
        tokens: tokens,
    }
    const res = await admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload);     
    console.log(`response: ${res}`);
```

---

I have verified that the tokens retrieved from the database are the same as the hardcoded ones with the following code.

```dart
exports.notifyUsers = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onCreate(async (liveSnapshot, context) => {
    const hardcodedTokens = [
         "e6erA_qM...",
         "ePU9p_CI...",
    ];
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').get();
    const tokens = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().token);
    let same = true;
    hardcodedTokens.forEach(el => {
        if (!tokens.includes(el)) {
           same = false;
        }
    });
    console.log(same);
})
```

This logs `true` in the firebase cloud functions console.

---

The function uses Node 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works.

```dart
async function getTokens() {
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').get();
    return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().token);
}

exports.notifyUsers = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const name = context.params.messageId;
    const message = snapshot.val().toString();
    const tokens = await getTokens();
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: `New message from ${name}`,
            body: message,
        },
        tokens: tokens,
    };
    await admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload);
})
```

---

I logged my response like below:

```dart
const res = await admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload);
console.log('response:', JSON.stringify(res));
```

This logged the following:
 `response: {"responses":[{"success":false,"error":{"code":"messaging/invalid-argument","message":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"sound\" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field."}},{"success":false,"error":{"code":"messaging/invalid-argument","message":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"sound\" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field."}}],"successCount":0,"failureCount":2}`

Based on this, I believe the problem was the `sound` argument in the notification part of the payload. It works after removing it.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem recently, and solved it by breaking out Android and iOS specific fields according to the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.basemessage.md#basemessage_interface) :

```
   const message = {
  "notification": {
    "title": `New message from ${name}`,
    "body": message,
  },
  'apns': {
    'payload': {
      'aps': {
        'badge': 1,
      },
    },
  },
  'android':{
    'notification':{
      'notificationCount': 1,
    },
  },
  "tokens": tokens,
}
```

Comment: Link goes to a 404.

Comment: this link should work:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210817164151/https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MulticastMessage

Not sure why there's a 404 on those docs.  [Here is a link to existing docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message), but they use `getMessaging()`, which seems to be an outdated method. 

I just used 

`{ notification: { title: "title", body: "body" }, content_available: true, tokens: [...] }`

as the payload and it worked as expected.

Comment: Found the current docs. They've updated their APIs to use typescript instead.  The payloads should be in the form of this interface:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.basemessage.md#basemessage_interface

Could you update the link?

Comment: I updated the link.